# How can I improve the performance of this double-for print?

Tags: java, performance, list, optimization

I have the following static method that prints the data imported from a 40.000 lines .xls spreadsheet.

Now, it takes about 27 seconds to print the data in the console and the memory consumption is huge.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public static void printSheetData(List<List<HSSFCell>> sheetData) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
        List<HSSFCell> list = (List<HSSFCell>) sheetData.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) list.get(j);
            System.out.print(cell.toString());
            if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I know, I know large data belong to a database, don't print output in the console, premature optimization is the root of all evils...

Comment: microoptimization: extract the sheetData.size() and list.size() calls.  It won't be measurable, though.

Comment: And you would probably be better off building a String (use StringBuffer) and then doing a single print of that, versus multiple prints.  That one, I think, will be measurable.

Comment: You may want to see how long it takes to simply System.out.println("some arbitrary string with about the same length as your current output") out 40,000 lines of data on your machine without worrying about the List operations, just to see how much of a bottleneck printing out is. maybe using a BufferedWriter to print to System.out could be quicker.

Comment: Is there a method to return a full range of cells (like one entire line) in the HSSF API?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to print a 40000 line spreadsheet to the console?

Comment: Just of curiosity: I wanted to see how println() scales. And for testing purposes. I wanted to be sure that i read the data correctly before further processing (the spreadsheet is complex enough). Sometimes testing with your own eyes is much better than testing with JUnit (shouldn't become a habit though)

Comment: (a) Who cares how println() to the console scales? Nobody can read 40,000 lines of console output; (b) so you are trying to tune a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than printing out each line one at a time, have you tried using a StringBuilder to create your large String, and then either printing that at one shot, or after so many lines have been added? You would be using the StringBuilder as a kind of buffer.

e.g.,

```
public static void printSheetData(List<List<HSSFCell>> sheetData) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
        List<HSSFCell> list = (List<HSSFCell>) sheetData.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) list.get(j);
            // System.out.print(cell.toString());
            strBuilder.append(cell.toString());
            if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                // System.out.print(", ");
                strBuilder.append(", ");
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("");
        strBuilder.append("\n");

        // consider testing strBuilder size here and printing it out if
        // it is greater than some pre-set, then re-initializing the 
        // strBuilder variable.
    }
    System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
}
```

Comment: Here are the results :
27 sec with the initial implementation
17 sec when using StringBuilder for each line
21 sec when using a large StringBuilder (your implementation) which means that it costs too much to print a huge StringBuilder with System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try log4j. It will bufferize for you.
Also, instead of loading the whole spreasheet in memory, can you print while reading it instead?